# Media Player crash

Tags: java, android

I am playing a sound when a button is pressed.  I have used this code before, but now in my new project my app crashes.

Here is my code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.sound1);

        Button play_button = (Button)this.findViewById(R.id.ring);
        play_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                mp.start();
            }
        });
    }
```

Here is my log:

```
dRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.sounds.apps.sounds, PID: 3660
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.media.MediaPlayer.start()' on a null object reference
 at com.sounds.apps.sound.MainActivity$1.onClick(MainActivity.java:30)
 at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
 at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
 at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Comment: Check that `R.raw.sound1` file exists and has a valid format

Comment: Make sure `mp` is not the name of a field variable

Comment: I'm sure mp is null. It was garbage collected when onCreate method was finished.